How to add a new custom QT dialog to an existing project?
I have a project with an existing .cpp,.h and .ui which is of type QMainWindow.
I want to add a button to the UI that opens a new custom dialog based on QDialog.
However, I cannot figure out exactly how to do this. The problem is, I can't figure out how to generate the new UI file so I can start editing it in QT Designer.
I've started with something like this:
StepsDialog.h:
#include "ui_StepsDialog.h"

#include <QDialog>
#include <QWidget>

class StepsDialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

 public:
  StepsDialog(QWidget* parent = 0);
  ~StepsDialog();

  Ui::StepsDialog* ui;
};

stepsdialog.cpp:
#include "stepsdialog.h"

StepsDialog::StepsDialog(QWidget* parent) : QDialog(parent)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
}

The problem is, that without the .ui file, QT won't auto-generate the ui_StepsDialog.h. I tried copying the existing MainWindow's UI, but that results in QT thinking I'm trying to make a MainWindow and not a QDialog which causes all sorts of issues.
What is the correct way to do this? I feel like there must be a simpler way. It seems like in Visual Studio there is, but I'm not using VS.
Do you just need to just take an existing UI file and manually edit it in a text editor to get it to be of type QDialog?

create .ui file first, then include it in the .h file, then use it in the .cpp

You open designer and press File then New and it opens a dialog and asks you what type of widget/ form to create: https://realpython.com/qt-designer-python/#using-qt-designers-new-form-dialog

you don't have to manually edit any .ui files. You can use Qt Designer for all your UI editing, exactly like this comment @drescherjm.

I see where I went wrong. If I use "New File" -> "QT" (not C/C++) -> "QT Designer Form Class" that seems to allow me to create a new dialog and the .cpp/.h. Thanks!
